# Errors In Polymorphism

Tags: java, error-handling, polymorphism, runtime-error

I am kinda new to java and I have a question about polymorphism and possible errors.
Assume that we have this:

```java
public interface Animal {
}

public abstract class Cat implements Animal{
}

public abstract class Fish implements Animal {
}

public class Salmon extends Fish{
}

public class Tiger extends Cat{
}
```

and Assume that we have something like this:

```java
Animal t1 = new Tiger();
Fish f1 = new Salmon();
Tiger t2= new Tiger();
Salmon s1 = new Salmon();
```

What is The errors in following lines (Compile Time Error, Runtime Error or No Error):

```java
Cat c1 = new Cat();
Cat c2 = (Tiger) t1;
Animal a1 = s1;
Animal a2 = new Animal();
Fish f1 = (Fish) t2;
Animal a3 = (Fish) s1;
Animal a4 = (Cat) new Tiger();
Cat c3 = (Cat) new Salmon();
```

I've Answered it like bellow but I've thought it's kinda weird that I found no Runtime Error. if all of them is correct can u make an example where we have runtime error (in this polymorphism concept)

My Answer:

```
a  compile error
b  no error
c  no error
d  compile error
e  compile error
f  no error
g  no error
h  compile error
```

Comment: Well, you can test your answers by simply running that code. You do not need anybody else for that.

Comment: I run the code, and this the answer i've got. I am confusing by how a runtime error can occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing on the part about "how to get to an exception at runtime".

You figured yourself that `Cat c3 = (Cat) new Salmon();` is wrong.
And obviously, the compiler can already tell you that.

Why? Because the compiler can "see" that you create a Salmon, and that you then want to treat that as Cat, which isn't meaningful.

The only thing you need to get "past" the compiler is to "hide" that fact, like:

```
Salmon s1 = new Salmon();
Animal a3 = (Fish) s1;
Cat c3 = (Cat) a3;
```

As soon as you introduce `a3`, you are able to "hide" the fact that `s1` is actually a Salmon.

**Of course**: even in my example, a *smarter* compiler could understand that `a3` must be a Salmon, can't be a Cat. But java plays it "simple and conservative" here. The compiler only recognizes the most basic casting violations, and for good or bad, the java language ignores many situations that *could* be detected at compile time, too. That makes it easier to implement compilers, the traddeoff is that your code is more exposed to such exceptions at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java only supports single inheritance of classes, it can verify whether casting between classes is potentially valid, because when casting, one of the classes must be an ancestor of the other. You can do up-cast, e.g. `Tiger` to `Cat`, or you can do down-cast, e.g. `Cat` to `Tiger`.

I'm ignoring the dumb identity cast, e.g. `Tiger` to `Tiger`, but it is of course allowed too.

You cannot cast a class to another class that it is not "related" to.

The same cannot be verified by the compiler regarding interfaces, since multiple inheritance is allowed, meaning that at compile-time, casting a class or interface to an interface is always possible, and casting an interface to a class or another interface is also always possible. The cast can only be verified at runtime.

Since you don't have two classes inheriting from the same base class, you cannot setup a runtime error for casting between classes. The compiler will always catch the error.

Since you only have one interface, and all the classes implement that interface, you cannot setup a runtime error for casting *to* an interface.

Which means that to setup a runtime error, you need to cast *from* an interface *to* a class that the real object is not compatible with, e.g. casting from `Animal t1` (real object `Tiger`) to `Salmon` or `Fish` would do it:

```java
Salmon s2 = (Salmon) t1; // ClassCastException: class Tiger cannot be cast to class Salmon
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are all correct. A newer compiler should find the cases, where the casts will fail in your example. The runtime exceptions will only be thrown in cases, where the compiler will lose track of the actual type, because the type is downcast:

```java
public Cat catterize(Animal a) {
    return (Cat) a; // this line should yield an unsafe typecast warning!
}

...

Salmon salmon = new Salmon();
Cat cat = catterize(salmon); // This is compiletime legal, but will ultimately throw a ClassCastException.
```